# jenkins on windows. Declarative pipeline jenkinsfile. how to set and get correct variable values

Tags: variables, jenkins

I use Jenkinsefile file to run the Stages.
It is in Jenkins pipeline installed on windows, Declarative pipeline.

On the begining I do:

```
pipeline {
    agent { label 'master'}
    environment {
        My_build_result       = 7
    }
....
Than
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'

                bat """
                cd Utils
                "C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2019b\\bin\\matlab.exe" -wait -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('automatic_tests\\run_test.m');"
                echo %errorlevel%
                set /a My_build_result_temp = %errorlevel%
                set My_build_result = %My_build_result_temp%
                """     
                script {
                    My_build_result = bat(returnStatus:true , script: "exit (2)").trim()                                
                    echo "My_build_result ${env.My_build_result}"               
                    if (My_build_result != 0) {
                        echo "inside if"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The variable My_build_result get value 7 at the begining
Inside the bat section, it suppose to get value 0 from %errorlevel%
Inside the script section it suppose to get value 2 
BUT
in the echo "My_build_result ${env.My_build_result}"  I get print of 7
(and it goes inside the if sentense)

How do I define variable that can be set value in bat"""
                                                  """
and in script """
"""
section of the stage
and also be familiar in another stages and in the post { always { .. }} at the end ???

BTW: add env.before My_build_result  (env.My_build_result  ) does not work
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first `bat` call, you are setting the environment variable only inside of the batch script environment. Environment variable values that are assigned through `set` don't persist when the script ends. Think of these like local variables. Simply use `returnStatus: true` to return the **last** value of `ERRORLEVEL`. There is no need to use `%ERRORLEVEL%` in the batch script here.

```groovy
steps {
    script {
        My_build_result = bat returnStatus: true, script: """
            cd Utils
            "C:\\Program Files\\MATLAB\\R2019b\\bin\\matlab.exe" -wait -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('automatic_tests\\run_test.m');"
        """
        // My_build_result now has the value of ERRORLEVEL from the last command
        // called in the batch script. 
    }
}
```

In the 2nd `bat` call the 1st mistake is to call the `trim()` method. Result type of `bat` step is `Integer`, when `returnStatus: true` is passed. The `trim()` method is only available when `returnStdout: true` is passed in which case the result type would be `String`. The 2nd mistake is to use brackets around the exit code value. The fixed code should look like:

```groovy
My_build_result = bat returnStatus: true, script: "exit 2"
// My_build_result now equals 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked
(Didn't find such an explanation in Jenkins web site)

Comment: @user3002345 Please upvote this answer and click the "accept" button to mark it as helpful.